# A hadith from Sunan Ibn Majah which I cannot find in Sunnah.com

Tags: hadith

[From Daily Hadith Online:](https://abuaminaelias.com/dailyhadithonline/2012/09/13/hadith-on-wisdom-the-best-believers-have-the-best-character-and-prepare-for-death-by-doing-good-works/)

> Ibn Umar reported: A man said, “O Messenger of Allah, which of the
>   believers is best?” The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be
>   upon him, said, “Those with the best character.” The man said, “Which
>   of the believers is the wisest?” The Prophet said, “Those who remember
>   death often and have best prepared for it with good deeds. Those are
>   the wisest.”
>
> Source: Sunan Ibn Mājah 4259

Why can't I find this hadith in sunnah.com?

Further, I have been told (without mentioning the source) a version where [this hadith from sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/36/94) is the continuation of the above hadith. What may be that source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here: http://sunnah.com/urn/1293620

[Here](https://archive.org/details/SunanIbnMajah_201405/page/n2501) is a scan from a published copy by Darus-Salam.

Answer (score 1):

Sunnah.com publishes two numbers for the Hadith. One for the Arabic and another for the English Darusalam print and there are whole chapters missing throughout the website.

Furthermore, the well known numbering system of the reports are those of later scholars (like Al-Mundhiri, Fawad Abdul-Baqi and As-Sindi) and not always the same from one manuscript to another. In fact, you'll find variation in the numbers from one publisher to the next in both Arabic and English depending on the editor of the text. Examples of this are many but the most common is Malik's Muwatta which has five numbering systems. Typically, the editor will leave a footnote that indicates this variation in number. Often times a report will be close in number but sometimes it is missing all together.

30 years ago, when Al-Luhaydan gave Ibn Jibrin his PhD, he commented that Ibn Jibrin narrated a Hadith from Abu Dawud's Sunnan that doesn't exist in the versions that have reached us but that the author had access to a manuscript that wasn't published.